# How to simply nested ternary logic in react while rendering different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have the following logic inside a react component where, I am rendering different component based on the boolean values. This peace of code is very difficult to understand. Are there anyways, I can simply that logic:

```
      {isEnabled ? (
      <>
        {!loading ? (
          <>
            {items.length === 0 ? (
              <>
                <ComponentOne/>
                <Container>
                  <img src={Image} alt="Image" />
                </Container>
              </>
            ) : (
              <ComponentTwo/>
            )}
          </>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <LoadingComponent/>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    ) : (
      <ComponentThree/>
    )}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue or you want to improve the logic?

Comment: I want to improve that logic, as it's seems to very difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably split it up into seperate components and pass parameters down the component tree for example

```
{isEnabled ? <IsLoadingComponent loading={loading} items={items}> : <ComponentThree/>}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to split the component up into a "Loading" version and a "Loaded" version so you don't have to handle both states in the same component. Then the component basically just renders the "Loading" or "Loaded" version depending on the flag.

But even without that, you can at least make that easier to debug by using `if`/`else if` etc. and assigning to a temporary variable:

```js
let comp;
if (isEnabled) {
    if (loading) {
        comp = <div>
            <LoadingComponent/>
        </div>;
    } else if (items.length === 0) {
        comp = <>
            <ComponentOne/>
            <Container>
                <img src={Image} alt="Image" />
            </Container>
        </>;
    } else {
        comp = <ComponentTwo />;
    }
} else {
    comp = <ComponentThree />;
}
```

Then just

```js
{comp}
```

where that nested conditional was.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a simple thing very complicated. What we can do instead is that make use of "&&".

```
  { isEnabled && loading && <LoaderComponent /> }
   {isEnabled && !items.length  &&
     <>
     <ComponentOne/>
     <Container>
        <img src={Image} alt="Image" />
     </Container>
  </>
}
{isEnabled && items.length && <ComponentTwo/>}
{!isEnabled && <ComponentThree />}
```

Comment: This still doesn't do what the original does. To do what the original does, it would need to repeat the test of `loading` in various places. (For instance: During loading, this renders either `ComponentOne` [as part of a fragment] or `ComponentTwo` depending on `items.length`, but neither should be rendered if `loading` is `true`.)   It's great to show an alternative and I like the direction this tries to go, but to me it' simportant that it handle the same cases as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Though I want to support the argument the others made (split into multiple components), you can already achieve a bit more readability by dropping unnecessary fragments (`<></>`) and/or parenthesis and by using *"better"*<sup>(opinion)</sup> indentation.

```
return (
  isEnabled
    ? loading
      ? <div><LoadingComponent/></div>
      : items.length === 0
        ? <> {/* this is the only place a fragment is actually needed */}
          <ComponentOne/>
          <Container>
            <img src={Image} alt="Image"/>
          </Container>
        </>
        : <ComponentTwo/>
    : <ComponentThree/>
);
```

---

Alternatively, *early returns* do help a lot with readability. For example:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  // ...snip...

  if (!isEnabled) {
    return <ComponentThree/>;
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <div><LoadingComponent/></div>;
  }

  if (items.length > 0) {
    return <ComponentThree/>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne/>
      <Container>
        <img src={Image} alt="Image"/>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```